# jQuery in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Is it possible to use jQuery in Knockout.

trying to use Knockout and Jquery for my script. [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swapnneld/R6zwv/20/) I am using Chrome.

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.DropPin = function (ev) {
        var x = ev.pageX - window.event.clientX;
        var y = ev.pageY - window.event.clientX;

        $('.pin').remove();
        x = (x - 10); //icon size
        y = (y - 30);
        var imgC = $('<img class="pin">');
        imgC.css('top', y);
        imgC.css('left', x);
        imgC.attr('src', "http://placekitten.com/200/300");
        imgC.appendTo(this);


    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

I can make it work [using javaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/swapnneld/R6zwv/21/) but want to know if jquery functions can be used in knockout and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most certainly can use jQuery along with Knockout. I think the problem with your fiddle is that you are trying to append a DOM node to a function:

```
imgC.appendTo(this);
```

`this` in this case refers to the `DropPin` function. You need to append the image to a DOM node:

`imgC.appendTo($("body"));`

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/M78as/) is an updated fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for answer.  Do you know why .offset() jquery Method is not working here...

Comment: What object are you trying to get the offset of?

Comment: X and Y coordinates of click event  on Div

Comment: @swapneel Here is a fiddle for the offset(): http://jsfiddle.net/qd2Xf/ It is actually the 2nd parameter of the function which is the event data, so you need to retrieve the target from that and pass it to jQuery

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the selector `imgC.appendTo(this);`, here `this` refer to the ViewModel not the body of the document , so you need to change it to `imgC.appendTo($('body'));`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/R6zwv/28/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's your example working: http://jsfiddle.net/R6zwv/25/

This is the wrong approach though, you'd generally want Knockout to manage the DOM. So you'd set up your templates, and then just deal with data in the observables.

He're a basic example of your template:

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: kittenSrc }, css: { top: kittenTop, left: kittenLeft }" />
<div id="map" data-bind="click: DropPin">add a image here</div>
```

Here's your example using observables: http://jsfiddle.net/R6zwv/29/

Comment: here's an [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/R6zwv/32/) that positions it where you click.  I just forget how to offset it from the top of the map.

Comment: also, another mod that lets you place [unlimited kittens](http://jsfiddle.net/R6zwv/33/)!